# Fun things to do at home

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, scrabble

What do I do when I get home, you ask?

> 1. Draw a dinosaur (11)
> 2. Read about an elite person (10)
> 3. Look at something that is written (10)
> 4. Learn about navy officers (8)
> 5. Take things back (7)
> 6. Work out a secret plan (8)
> 7. Watch from the side (9)

Well, maybe it is a little bit distorted...

**What do I actually do when i'm at home?**

---

Hint:

> What do all words have in common?

Comment: My apologies for my edit. I thought QuantumTwinkie's answer was the accepted one, but I was terribly mistaken; [tag:anagram] therefore does ***not*** belong in this question. So sorry for that. I have taken it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Draw a dinosaur (11)

   > triceratops
2. Read about an elite person (10)

   > aristocrat
3. Look at something that is written (10)

   > transcript
4. Learn about navy officers (8)

   > captains
5. Take things back (7)

   > retract
6. Work out a secret plan (8)

   > conspire
7. Watch from the side (9)

   > spectator

If we

> take the shortest word with subsequences that anagram to each of these words,

we find that at home you

> **procrastinate**.

Answer (score 7):

> These have to do with anagrams of steal, teals, slate, tales, least, and slate.

Draw a dinosaur

> On a slate

Read about an elite person

> Tesla

Look at something that is written

> You may read tales.

Learn about navy officers

> Teals, because navy is teal.

Take things back

> Steal

Work out a secret plan

> ?

Watch from the side

> ?

But

> I have least and stale left.

Comment: Nice answer, but that's not it. I edited the tags because I realize now it wan't accurate